# hostTab on android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm use scroll bar in android host tab but it is not work I'm add 4 tab but I'm want to display 3 at the same time other view when scroll

and how make layout bottom

this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 >
 </FrameLayout>
```